# zsh: disable glob in variable substitution

Tags: shell, zsh

In ksh I can pass variable to a string operator pattern:

```
m=h*; a=shy;  print ${a%%${m}}
```

Will give me the result 's', but in zsh, the * seems to be extanded and no way to avoid this:

```
m=h*; a=shy; print ${a%%${m}}
m=h*; a=shy; noglob print ${a%%${m}}
```

Will both still give me 'shy'. So how can I have the * pattern passed to string operator?

Comment: Thanks for an interesting question, perhaps this email from a list can set you on the right path: http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2004/msg00384.html (I searched for zsh string interpolation.) Oh, and am FAQ on the concept: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html

Answer (score 4):

I have the solution, apply a '~' in the pattern.

```
m=h*; a=shy;  print ${a%%$~m}
```

Quoting from `man zshexpn`:

> **${~spec}**
>      Turn  on  the  `GLOB_SUBST`  option  for  the evaluation of spec; if the `~` is doubled, turn it off.  When this option is set,
>   the string resulting from the expansion will be interpreted as a pattern anywhere that is possible, such as in filename expansion
>   and filename generation and pattern-matching contexts like the right hand side of the `=` and `!=` operators in conditions.